# Reading http/2 push stream fails with error -505

Tags: node.js, stream, push, http2

I'm trying to read an http/2 push stream, but the code below fails with an error. When I use the same URL in Chrome browser, I receive the 'heartbeat' being generated by the stream server and can see data coming in as well. Any pointers? My goal is simply to read all the JSON push responses being generated by the server.

```
Error:
{ Error [ERR_HTTP2_ERROR]: Protocol error
    at Http2Session.onSessionInternalError [as error] (internal/http2/core.js:637:26)
  code: 'ERR_HTTP2_ERROR',
  name: 'Error [ERR_HTTP2_ERROR]',
  errno: -505 }
```

Node.JS Code:

```
const http2 = require('http2');
const client = http2.connect('http://api.service.com/absolute/path/subscribe?api_key={key}');

const req = client.request();
req.setEncoding('utf8');

req.on('response', (headers, flags) => {
  console.log(headers);
});

let data = '';
req.on('data', (d) => data += d);
req.on('end', () => {
    console.log('end');
    console.log(data); 
    client.destroy()
});
req.end();
```

Side Note: I'm new to Node.js, and http/2 push stream is a new topic for me as well, so consider me a beginner, struggling with this.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved with some help, using 'request' library:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

```
const request = require("request");

const getPushData = () => {
    let completeResponse = "";
    request
    .get('http://api.service.com/absolute/path/subscribe?api_key={key}')
    .on('response', (response)=>{
        console.log("Response received successfully");
    })
    .on('data', (chunk)=>{
        console.log("Receiving the chunk...");
        console.log(chunk);
        let dataReceived = new Buffer(chunk).toString("utf8");
        console.log(dataReceived);

        completeResponse += chunk;        
    })
    .on('error', (err)=>{
        console.log("Something went wrong:");
        console.log(err.message);
    })
    .on("end", ()=>{
        console.log("The complete data received is:");
        console.log(completeResponse);
        let jsonObj = JSON.parse(completeResponse); 
        console.log(jsonObj);
    });
}

getPushData();
```

Side Note: The problem with this script is that if connection drops, the stream doesn't resume.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want, but `request` does not support HTTP2. If your code works now, it must be because the connection falls back to HTTP 1.1